# Tailwind styles not reloading

Tags: javascript, webpack, tailwind-css

***Edit:** I just checked the webpack output, and it is emitting a different `index.html` when I save. Added the output to the question below

***Edit2:** It's not to do with dev server, it's a config option in `tailwind.config.js`. See answer below :)

---

Am new to using Tailwind and am struggling to set it up with Webpack (specifically HtmlWebpackPlugin and webpack-dev-server).

I can't seem to get it to watch the html for class changes, and I figured that might be to do with the tailwing config content property pointing to the wrong path, but I'm not sure what it should be?

My webpack config `devServer` object points to static resources in 'dist', but that results in no styling at all, and pointing it at `src/index.html` (which HtmlWebpackPlugin uses as a template) doesnt' refresh the styles when there are changes.

It's probably a very simple mistake, but any ideas where I'm going wrong?

File structure

[image: file structure]

Webpack.config.js

```js
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    mode: 'production',
    entry: './src/index.js',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: '[name]bundle.js',
        clean: true,
    },
    devServer: {
        static: {
            directory: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        },
        port: 5000,
        open: true,
        hot: true,
        compress: true,
        historyApiFallback: true,
    },
    module: {
        rules: [{
                test: /\.js$/i,
                include: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    options: {
                        presets: ['@babel/preset-env'],
                    },
                },
            },
            {
                test: /\.html$/i,
                loader: "html-loader",
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/i,
                include: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
                use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'postcss-loader'],
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|jpeg|gif)$/i,
                type: 'asset/resource',
            },

        ],
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            filename: 'index.html',
            template: './src/index.html',
        }),
    ],
}
```

Tailwind.config.js

```js
module.exports = {
    content: ['./src/*.html'], // doesn't reload on changes
    //content: ['./dist/*.html] // no styling at all
    theme: {
        extend: {},
    },
    variants: {
        extend: {},
    },
    plugins: [],
}
```

Package.json

```json
{
    "name": "tailwind-webpack",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "",
    "main": "index.js",
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "webpack serve",
        "build": "webpack"
    },
    "keywords": [],
    "author": "",
    "license": "ISC",
    "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/core": "^7.17.9",
        "@babel/preset-env": "^7.16.11",
        "babel-loader": "^8.2.5",
        "css-loader": "^6.7.1",
        "html-loader": "^4.1.0",
        "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.5.0",
        "postcss": "^8.4.16",
        "postcss-loader": "^6.2.1",
        "postcss-preset-env": "^7.7.2",
        "style-loader": "^3.3.1",
        "tailwindcss": "^3.1.8",
        "webpack": "^5.74.0",
        "webpack-cli": "^4.10.0",
        "webpack-dev-server": "^4.9.3"
    }
}
```

src/index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Email Subscribe</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- Background Container-->
        <div class="div flex items-center justify-center h-screen bg-zinc-700">
            <!-- Card -->
            <div class="bg-zinc-800 p-2 mx-6 rounded-2xl">
                <!-- Flex Container -->
                <div class="flex-col md:flex-row rounded-l-xl">
                    <!-- Image -->
                    <img src="./images/image.jpg" 
                         alt="" 
                         class="object-fit rounded-xl h-80 md:h-64 md:rounded-l-xl md:rounded-r-none">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

webpack output

```
assets by status 72.8 KiB [cached] 1 asset
assets by path *.js 131 KiB
  asset mainbundle.js 131 KiB [emitted] [minimized] (name: main) 1 related asset
  asset 179.4bdb2b52a0f30be06877.hot-update.js 105 bytes [emitted] [immutable] [hmr] [minimized] (name: main)
asset index.html 589 bytes [emitted]
asset main.4bdb2b52a0f30be06877.hot-update.json 25 bytes [emitted] [immutable] [hmr]
Entrypoint main 131 KiB = mainbundle.js 131 KiB 179.4bdb2b52a0f30be06877.hot-update.js 105 bytes
runtime modules 27.3 KiB 13 modules
orphan modules 18.8 KiB [orphan] 8 modules
cacheable modules 180 KiB
  modules by path ./node_modules/ 166 KiB
    modules by path ./node_modules/style-loader/dist/runtime/*.js 5.75 KiB 6 modules
    modules by path ./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client/ 53.5 KiB 4 modules
    modules by path ./node_modules/webpack/hot/*.js 4.3 KiB 4 modules
    modules by path ./node_modules/html-entities/lib/*.js 81.3 KiB 4 modules
    modules by path ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/runtime/*.js 2.33 KiB 2 modules
    ./node_modules/ansi-html-community/index.js 4.16 KiB [built] [code generated]
    ./node_modules/events/events.js 14.5 KiB [built] [code generated]
  modules by path ./src/ 14.6 KiB
    ./src/index.js 47 bytes [built] [code generated]
    ./src/style.css 2.37 KiB [built] [code generated]
    ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js!./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js!./src/style.css 12.2 KiB [built] [code generated]
webpack 5.74.0 compiled successfully in 2135 ms
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I discovered the answer in a starter video

in your `tailwind.config.js` file you need to add the `purge` option

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  jit: true,
  purge: ["./src/**/*.html", "./src/**/*.{js, jsx, ts, tsx}"],
  content: [],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  variant: {
    extend: {}
  }
  plugins: [],
}
```

Worked for me, hope it helps someone else

Good description [here](https://youtu.be/2JKGGMD4fXk?t=1100)

Comment: unfortunately didn't work with tailwindcss v3